# Can I set the timeout for UdpClient in C#?

Tags: c#, timeout, udpclient

I am wondering whether I can set a timeout value for UdpClient receive method.

I want to use block mode, but because sometimes udp will lost packet, my program udpClient.receive will hang there forever.

any good ideas how I can manage that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

What Filip is referring to is nested within the socket that `UdpClient` contains (`UdpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout`).

You can also use the async methods to do this, but manually block execution:

```
var timeToWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

var udpClient = new UdpClient( portNumber );
var asyncResult = udpClient.BeginReceive( null, null );
asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne( timeToWait );
if (asyncResult.IsCompleted)
{
    try
    {
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = null;
        byte[] receivedData = udpClient.EndReceive( asyncResult, ref remoteEP );
        // EndReceive worked and we have received data and remote endpoint
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // EndReceive failed and we ended up here
    }
} 
else
{
    // The operation wasn't completed before the timeout and we're off the hook
}
```

Comment: This was a long time ago! That looks ok now. WaitOne also returns a result you can use to determine if it timed out.

Answer (score 68):

There is a `SendTimeout` and a `ReceiveTimeout` property that you can use in the `Socket` of the `UdpClient`.

Here is an example of a 5 second timeout:

```
var udpClient = new UdpClient();

udpClient.Client.SendTimeout = 5000;
udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;

...
```

Comment: This only works if you are doing a synchronous send/receive. For ansynchronous calls, you could use `Task.Delay` to create your own timeout, e.g. `Task.WhenAny(udpClient.ReceiveAsync(), Task.Delay(5000))`;

Comment: Well of course! How did I miss that simple solution! Thanks for your comment AJ!

Comment: @AJRichardson well, I don't think that is a good way to go, 'cause when the timer -ask completed the process will resume BUT udpClient.ReceiveAsync() will still be on waiting...
I would suggest maybe something like: 
Task.WaitAny(new[] { udpClient.ReceiveAsync() }, waitTimeOutInMs);

Comment: @IvandroJao You are correct, although I don't know that your code will fix the issue. It sounds like you should close the socket in the timeout case: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12642359/1299394

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it appears that `UdpClient` is broken when it comes to timeouts.  I tried to write a server with a thread containing only a Receive which got the data and added it to a queue.  I've done this sort of things for years with TCP.  The expectation is that the loop blocks at the receive until a message comes in from a requester.  However, despite setting the timeout to infinity:

```
_server.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 0; //block waiting for connections
_server.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 0);
```

the socket times out after about 3 minutes.

The only workaround I found was to catch the timeout exception and continue the loop.  This hides the Microsoft bug but fails to answer the fundamental question of why this is happening.

Comment: I guess there's an internal timeout of 200000 ms or so?

Answer (score 3):

There is a ReceiveTimeout property you can use.

Comment: ReceiveTimeout is for sync calls only (ie: Receive method)

Answer (score 3):

you can do like this:

```
udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 5000);
```