# Multiple threads of one type, one function

Tags: c#, multithreading, function, for-loop

First i am sorry if there is another thread like this and i didnt saw it!
My problem is: I want to create multiple threads. But these threads must execute same function.
How i can make this happen?
Like so :

```
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
  Thread t = new Thread(myFunction);
  t.Start();
}
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: What is your problem? Is there any exception thrown?

Comment: That *does* work. It'll be absolutely fine. Now tell us what's really going wrong in your actual situation.

Comment: Your code will run `myFunction` 20 times, each time on a different thread. If this is what you want, then just compile your code and see for yourself. If you're looking to parallelize *one* run of `myFunction` across 20 threads, well, that's another story. In any case, please be more specific about what's your problem.

Comment: yes Theodoros that is what i want

Comment: @ЛюбославЛюбенов I named two possible things. Do you mean you wanted the second one? One run of `myFunction` performed by multiple threads? If that's the case, you'll have to post the code of `myFunction` specifically, as there is no general way to parallelize any piece of code.

Comment: first one. its because my myfunction.

Comment: Please don't add “[solved]” to your question. Instead, accept the answer that solved your problem. If none of them did, post your own answer and then accept that.

Comment: @ЛюбославЛюбенов I see. Please go to the answer that has helped you (below) and click the check mark if the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use tasks? It is also Async (since that is what you are looking for I think.

```
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
  Task task = new Task(new Action(myFunction));
  task.Start();
}
```

The difference can be found here:

[What is the difference between task and thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130194/what-is-the-difference-between-task-and-thread)

Comment: ok but what is difference between task and thread?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130194/what-is-the-difference-between-task-and-thread

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anythign wrong with what you have (maybe if you share some of the code in myFunction, we could get a better picture).

I would recommend that you either use the ThreadPool, or that you use the Task Parallel library instead of manually creating your own thread.

Here are a few techniques:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, 20, myFunction); // myFunction should accept an int, and return void)
```

If the signature of myFunction is different, you could use a lambda to "translate" -- be aware that you are calling a function that calls a function here:

```
Parallel.For(0, 20, i => myFunction()); //(I could pass any param to my function in this example)
```

Here's a a threadpool way

```
System.Threading.Threadpool.QueueUserWorkItem(myFunction) // myFunction needs to accept an object
```

// here's how to queue it to the threadpool with any signature

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s => myFunction());
```

Another poster already mentioned using Tasks to do it.  If what you are doing is pretty simple, I would just use the Parallel.For.