# Event's action performed on new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, event-handling, observablecollection

I have an observable collection

```
var QueryList = new ObservableCollection<QueryData>();
```

Suppose I have implemented a method OnQueryListCollectionChanged for when this collection's CollectionChanged event is triggered.  The trick is that I would like this method to execute on a new thread.

```
QueryList.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(new ThreadStart(OnQueryListCollectionChanged));
```

I know the line above is incorrect but I am not exactly sure how to have the Collection's NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler delegate to point the method OnQueryListCollectionChanged to a new thread.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct means of having the events handled on a separate thread from the registering of a handler.

You could point the event to a method and then just spawn a new thread from there to do your work, yes, the event being raised may interrupt your main thread, but only long enough for you to start your new thread.

As a side note, I'd recommend against using Threads directly and instead making use of the newer `Task` classes, see: [What is the difference between task and thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130194/what-is-the-difference-between-task-and-thread)