# Diffrence between Thread and Task

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

would like to get some information in nice manner way as i am bit confused about diffrence between those two guys. Is that true that first and second createinh completly separate thread or? What is the diffrence here. Please og nice explanation as there is lost information on network including ThreadPool, Thread, Tasks and so on i am bit lost which one should be used for which purposes.

**First guy:**

```
DataInThread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(Somemethod))
```

**Second guy:**

```
 Dim t As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() Somemethod()

End Function)
```

**Additional questions**:

> 1. Is that true that for first guy completely new brain thread will be created?
> 2. Is that true that second guy - will be placed either to completely new brain thread or to the threadpool (means within same gui thread).
>      And that's depends directly to Task StartNew to decide what to do.
>      Does it correct understanding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between task and thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130194/what-is-the-difference-between-task-and-thread)

Comment: Although the duplicate I pointed to is about C# there is no difference in this case between C# and VB.NET

Comment: that's really nice topic. Anyway additional questions in main topic.

Comment: This site allows one question per post. The second additional question is not clear. Rewrite it and post it separately. But before you do read some documentation on tasks.