# c# how to thread through loops

Tags: c#, multithreading

Hello I was wondering how people make loops threaded for example

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Is it possible to have one thread for every loop?
so,
Thread 1: 0
Thread 2: 1
Thread 3: 2
ect..

and if so, how would I cap the threads ?

Comment: have you tried searching ?

Comment: Console.Writeline will undo your threading attempts as it will block, check https://gist.github.com/timgaunt/3620149

Comment: also, you may want to use parallel loops https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the name of it so I wasn't sure if i'd find it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the parallel for

This:

```
for(int i=0; i <=10; i++) 
{  
    Console.WriteLine(i); 
}
```

Becomes this:

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, i =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
});
```

This will spawn one task per iteration of the loop. One of the overloads of parallel takes in the parallel options which lets set the maximum number of tasks running cuncurrently. Official docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992418(v=vs.110).aspx

Note there is some difference between a thread and a task in C#: [What is the difference between task and thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130194/what-is-the-difference-between-task-and-thread)

If you have a list of items to process I recommend the parallel foreach: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You've suggested that this solution does what the OPs wants, but you haven't answered the OPs specific questions.

Comment: I didn't even notice the second part of the question, fixed answer

Comment: Thank you @Wallace