# ASP.NET Core, On request immediately return 200, then run a method

Tags: asp.net-core

can I call a GET request, and have it immediately return a 200 response, then run a method.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Yes, but why?  What's the use case? That will help us guide you in the right direction.

Comment: No method can do anything *after* it returns.  But there are a variety of things you *can* do to asynchronously execute operations in an application.  It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish or why.

Comment: Check this out [fire and forget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335345/web-api-fire-and-forget) , but keep in mind that this method has a lot of caveats explained in the linked post. For doing offline jobs you should consider using a worker service

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an asp.net core API template and I think that you are, the ControllerBase class that you inherited have `CreatedAtRoute` method that can run another API after returning 200 response like this :

```
return CreatedAtRoute("GetCustomer", new {CustomerName = Sajed} );
```

Comment: Will this work with dependency injection?

Comment: What do you mean ? if you are returning an ActionResult in your API action method, you can return and route using the method i wrote for you @TianOpenlab

Comment: Was it what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't - no code is executed after the return statement in a method.

In this case, once your handler returns a result, the scope changes and you programmatically can never reach code within that method after the return statement.

However, I suspect your question is more regarding ways to implement "fire and forget" endpoints, which do not block the consumer & make them wait for a response which they do not need at this moment in time.

That problem can be solved using asynchronous message queuing systems like RabbitMQ, Amazon SQS, Azure ASQs etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider two things:

- Obviously, no code will be executed after the `return` keyword
- After returning response all objects with the lifetime of `Transient` and `Scoped` will be disposed

You can use the background task to execute your method after returning an immediate response. You can use:

- [Quartz.Net](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet)
- [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)

Or check this question [What is the simplest way to run a single background task from a controller in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62222712/1385614)

You can also use `async void` but is not recommended to use. It's used when developers are trying to implement fire and forget patterns triggered by a controller action. Here is [more info](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#async-void).