# Activity Indicator is dismissed before images are loaded

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, activity-indicator

I have a question. My activity Indicator dismisses before my images are finished loading from my api. Is it because the call to the api is async? If so, how can I make sure the call is done or the images are loaded on the screen before dismissing my activity indicator?

The activity indicator code in my XAML looks like this:

```
  <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                             IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
                             VerticalOptions="Center"
                             HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
```

My property (which is located in viewmodel base):

```
private bool isBusy;
        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get { return isBusy; }
            set { SetProperty(ref isBusy, value); }
        }
```

And this is the code where I set the property:

```
  public override async void OnNavigatingTo(NavigationParameters navParams)
        {
            if(navParams.ContainsKey("query"))
            {
                var query = (string)navParams["query"];
                IsBusy = true;
                await DisplayImages(query);
                IsBusy = false;

            }
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Async/await doesn't make it run on a background thread. How is `DisplayImages` implemented?

Comment: Check that DisplayImages method contains async keyword.

Comment: Just makes a call to an api endpoint and sets the object it gets to the property that it should bind to. It does contain async keyword.

Comment: You need to use a background thread.

Comment: How? With this?  "System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
 {
      //Add your code here.
 }).ConfigureAwait(false);"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at my computer, and it's tricky to do on this device, but here goes...

**Option 1: BackgroundWorker**

Async/await doesn't make it run on a background thread, you need the loading to occur on a background thread. And be aware that [Tasks and threads are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130194/what-is-the-difference-between-task-and-thread).

Create a field on your class, type `BackgroundWorker`. Hook up the DoWork event of that field to be a method containing:

```
            IsBusy = true;
            DisplayImages(query);
            IsBusy = false;
```

And where those lines used to be, call `RunWorkerAsync` on your field. You can put the value of `query` into a field so it can be used from the DoWork method.

**Option 2: an actual thread**

Put the 3 lines in a method called `Load(string query)`. Where those lines used to be, do this:

```
myNewThread = new Thread(() => Load(query));
myNewThread.Start();
```

I think `myNewThread` needs to be a field so it doesn't get garbage collected.

Comment: @Euridice01 Edited answer to add another option.

Answer (score 0):

Implement in your method using:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{
   //load your images here
   //Lastly set IsBusy to false
});
```