# How to create a thread with multiple parameters?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have this function

```
static void appUpdater(string appName, string proccessName)
{
    /**/
}
```

I need to create a thread for each of the applications update, but ThreadStart and ParameterizedThreadStart do not match delegate

```
Thread wms = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(appUpdater));
wms.Start("WMS","StuMenu");
```

Comment: Why are you using `Thread` and not `Task`?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I'm new to c#, how would i use task instead ?
how do they differ ?

Comment: Yes you should be using `Task` instead: `var task = Task.Run(() => appUpdater("WMS", "StuMenu"));` Also, [the difference between Thread and Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130194/what-is-the-difference-between-task-and-thread).

Comment: Why not use the [.NET thread pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool)?

Comment: @UweKeim - How does that answer the OP's question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it super easy by just doing this:

```
Thread wms = new Thread(() => appUpdater("WMS", "StuMenu"));
wms.Start();
```

Alternatively, use a `Task` - tasks are more modern and you'll find built in language support for doing clever things with them. Don't learn threads, learn tasks.

```
Task t = Task.Run(() => appUpdater("WMS", "StuMenu"));
```

Comment: How does suggesting to use a Task answers the OP's question?

Comment: It shows how to start a thread/task without parameters, but still calls the method, that the OP wants to call, with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `Thread.Start()` only accepts one parameter of type `object`. But you could for instance pass a custom object or a dictionary instead

**Object:**

```
class ThreadParameters {
    public string p1 {get;set;}
    public string p2 {get;set;}
}

static void appUpdater(object p) {
    ThreadParameters tp = p as ThreadParameters;
}

Thread wms = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(appUpdater));
wms.Start(new ThreadParameters{p1="p1", p2= "p2"});
```

**Dictionary:**

```
static void appUpdater(object p) {
    Dictionary<string, object> tp = p as Dictionary<string, object>;
}

Thread wms = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(appUpdater));
wms.Start(new Dictionary<string, object>{{"p1", "p1"}, {"p2", "p2}});
```

But depending on what your needs are, a `Task` may be the better way.

Comment: `appUpdater(p : object)`? Different language I guess.

Comment: @FCin yes, too deep into typescript right at the moment. updated . thx