# C# tasks are not executed in new thread

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, asynchronous, task

I have an async function that doesn't throw anything:

```cs
public async Task SomeLongComputations()
{
    // do some stuff that takes a lot of time
}
```

that I just want it to run in the background, without intervening the main thread:

```cs
public void SomeFunctionInMainThread()
{
    _ = SomeLongComputations();
}
```

But when I debugged the code in Visual Studio and set a breakpoint inside `SomeLongComputations`, it still shows that it is ran on main thread (thread id == 1).

---

Some additional context, not sure if it is relevant:

- I am developing an extension for Visual Studio
- The threads are created inside an event handler for `ITextBuffer.Changed` and `IWpfTextView.LayoutChanged`
- In the debug window, I can still see other threads

Comment: Slapping `async Task` in front of your method doesn't actually run any code in a different thread.  Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: You should expand `// do some stuff that takes a lot of time` cause just marking method `async` will not make it running in another thread.

Comment: Oh, so `_ = Something` does not execute the task in new thread?

Comment: @FalconUA depends on what is in `Something`.

Comment: @GuruStron there are some `await` stuffs in `SomeLongComputations`, but I want the whole function `SomeLongComputations` to run in different thread. How can I achieve that? Or I am misunderstanding what `Task` are in C#?

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code. There is no indication of any async processing in code shown. You've also hopefully read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130194/what-is-the-difference-between-task-and-thread  - if not - reading that will help with the [edit]...

Comment: Read the blog from Stephen Cleary and start at [Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks, but this post is mainly to clear my misunderstanding of how tasks works. Thanks everyone to point out to my misunderstandings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just want it to run in the background, without intervening the main
> thread:

That'd look more like:

```
public async void SomeFunctionInMainThread()
{
    await SomeLongComputations();
}

public Task SomeLongComputations()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // do some stuff that takes a lot of time
    });
}
```

Comment: Please, no ... read [Task.Run Etiquette Examples](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-even-in.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just adding async will not make the task run on another thread.
You can use Task.Run and call the method to run it in background. See link here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netcore-3.1