# How to handle multiple tasks running in parallel at different intervals inside a C# based Windows service?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, task, task-parallel-library

I already have some experience in working with threads in Windows but most of that experience comes from using Win32 API functions in C/C++ applications. When it comes to .NET applications however, I am often not sure about how to properly deal with multithreading. There are threads, tasks, the TPL and all sorts of other things I can use for multithreading but I never know when to use which of those options.
I am currently working on a C# based Windows service which needs to periodically validate different groups of data from different data sources. Implementing the validation itself is not really an issue for me but I am unsure about how to handle all of the validations running simultaneously.
I need a solution for this which allows me to do all of the following things:

1. Run the validations at different (predefined) intervals.
2. Control all of the different validations from one place so I can pause and/or stop them if necessary, for example when a user stops or restarts the service.
3. Use the system ressources as efficiently as possible to avoid performance issues.

So far I've only had one similar project before where I simply used `Thread` objects combined with a `ManualResetEvent` and a `Thread.Join` call with a timeout to notify the threads about when the service is stopped. The logic inside those threads to do something periodically then looked like this:

```
while (!shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
{
    if (DateTime.Now > nextExecutionTime)
    {
        // Do something
        nextExecutionTime = nextExecutionTime.AddMinutes(interval);
    }

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

While this did work as expected, I've often heard that using threads directly like this is considered "oldschool" or even a bad practice. I also think that this solution does not use threads very efficiently as they are just sleeping most of the time. How can I achive something like this in a more modern and efficient way?
If this question is too vague or opinion-based then please let me know and I will try my best to make it as specific as possible.

Comment: Simplified: Use `Task` instead of `Thread`. Prefer `async` `await` syntax.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130194/what-is-the-difference-between-task-and-thread

Comment: Not sure if this lib might help https://www.hangfire.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question feels a bit broad but we can use the provided code and try to improve it.

Indeed the problem with the existing code is that for the majority of the time it holds thread blocked while doing nothing useful (sleeping). Also thread wakes up every second only to check the interval and in most cases go to sleep again since it's not validation time yet. Why it does that? Because if you will sleep for longer period - you might block for a long time when you signal `shutdownEvent` and then join a thread. `Thread.Sleep` doesn't provide a way to be interrupted on request.

To solve both problems we can use:

1. Cooperative cancellation mechanism in form of `CancellationTokenSource` + `CancellationToken`.
2. `Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`.

For example:

```
async Task ValidationLoop(CancellationToken ct) {
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested) {
        try {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            if (now >= _nextExecutionTime) {
                // do something
                _nextExecutionTime = _nextExecutionTime.AddMinutes(1);
            }

            var waitFor = _nextExecutionTime - now;
            if (waitFor.Ticks > 0) {
                await Task.Delay(waitFor, ct);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) {
            // expected, just exit
            // otherwise, let it go and handle cancelled task 
            // at the caller of this method (returned task will be cancelled).
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            // either have global exception handler here
            // or expect the task returned by this method to fail
            // and handle this condition at the caller
        }
    }
}
```

Now we do not hold a thread any more, because `await Task.Delay` doesn't do this. Instead, after specificed time interval it will execute the subsequent code on a free thread pool thread (it's more complicated that this but we won't go into details here).

We also don't need to wake up every second for no reason, because `Task.Delay` accepts cancellation token as a parameter. When that token is signalled - `Task.Delay` will be immediately interrupted with exception, which we expect and break from the validation loop.

To stop the provided loop you need to use `CancellationTokenSource`:

```
private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

And you pass its `_cts.Token` token into the provided method. Then when you want to signal the token, just do:

```
_cts.Cancel();
```

To futher improve the resource management - IF your validation code uses any IO operations (reads files from disk, network, database access etc) - use `Async` versions of said operations. Then also while performing IO you will hold no unnecessary threads blocked waiting.

Now you don't need to manage threads yourself anymore and instead you operatate in terms of tasks you need to perform, letting framework \ OS manage threads for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response! Is there anything I need to do in terms of waiting for all created validations to stop before exiting the process? I want to give all validations a chance to stop after signaling the token. In my old application I did this via a `Thread.Join()` call with a timeout before I would force-terminate the threads by calling `Thread.Abort()`.

Comment: @Chris yes, the `ValidationLoop` in my example returns `Task`. You can save that task somewhere (in a similar manner you now do with Thread) and then call `task.Wait(<timeout>)` after cancellation, similar to `Thread.Join`. There is no analog to `Thread.Abort` though - all cancellation for tasks is cooperative (which means code you are trying to cancel should be aware of such possibility and cooperate, like we do with using `CancellationToken`).

Comment: If you write code correctly - there will be no need for analog of `Thread.Abort` though. You should pass `CancellationToken` to _any_ asynchronous method you use which accepts it, then the only code it can stuck at is CPU-bound code which for validation can't take too long.

Comment: Thanks again! Just two more questions: In which case is the OperationCanceledException being thrown? Isn't the whole point of this to "ask" the validation logic to stop instead of force-terminating it? And how/where can I handle when one of the validations crashes so I can restart it?

Comment: @Chris this exception is thrown when you await something passing `CancellationToken` to it. In this example - it is thrown by `await Task.Delay(waitFor, ct)`. It is NOT thrown at random time like for example `Thread.Abort` does - the code inside `Task.Delay` handles cancellation and throws this exception. That means cancellation does not force terminate validation - exception can be thrown by particular statements (and those are statements which can usually take long time), in this example only by `Task.Delay`.

Comment: So if validation is in progress and you cancel - it will continue until in reaches `Task.Delay` (or until the while loop check) and only then it will terminate. As for validation crash - you should just put try catch around validation itself, because the loop itself cannot crash and so doesn't need to be restarted. Or you can put try catch inside while loop like in the example.

Comment: @Chris by the way if your validation does not use any IO (database, file access etc) - you can use simple timer to achieve similar results. Just stop timer as the first statement in the callback handler, then start timer again as the last statement (after validation) so that it fires again exactly at `_nextExecutionTime`. Timers of course also do not hold a thread, and you can just stop them on service shutdown.

Answer (score -1):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
Subject<bool> starter = new Subject<bool>();

IObservable<Unit> query =
    starter
        .StartWith(true)
        .Select(x => x
            ? Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)).SelectMany(y => Observable.Start(() => Validation()))
            : Observable.Never<Unit>())
        .Switch();
        
IDisposable subscription = query.Subscribe();
```

That fires off the `Validation()` method every `5.0` seconds.

When you need to pause and resume, do this:

```
starter.OnNext(false);
// Now paused

starter.OnNext(true);
// Now restarted.
```

When you want to stop it all call `subscription.Dispose()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could the person who voted down this answer please explain why? Is there something wrong or problematic about this solution or what is bad about it?