# Confusion with async networking in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

I wrote a C# game server that usually has several hundred people connected to it, and based it on [this example from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example). The players are always sending data back and forth, and the connections are rarely idle.
I have started wondering though: is every player connection launching its own Thread? Would it be better performance-wise if I recoded it to use 'Tasks/Await/etc' instead?

**[EDIT]**
Is the way I'm calling Thread.Sleep() an appropriate way to throttle someone's connection? Or, instead of using Thread.Sleep(), should I have it launch a task with Task.Delay() that contains SendBytes()

```
public class Server
{
    void Listen()
    {
        IPAddress IpAddr = IPAddress.Parse(ipv4_local);
        IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IpAddr, port);
        listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        listener.Bind(ipEnd);
        listener.Listen(5000);

        while (true)
        {
            listener_allDone.Reset();
            listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptConnection), listener);
            listener_allDone.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    void AcceptConnection(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        listener_allDone.Set();

        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        Player player = new Player(handler);
        player.InitReceive();
    }
}
```

And the player class, where Thread.Sleep() is used to throttle...

```
public class Player
{
    public Socket socket;
    public byte[] send_buffer = new byte[2048];
    public byte[] receive_buffer = new byte[2048];

    public Player(Socket socket)
    {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    void SendBytes()
    {
        socket.BeginSend(send_buffer, 0, send_buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnSendComplete, null);
    }

    void OnSendComplete(System.IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        int bytes_sent = socket.EndSend(iar);
        if (MORE BYTES TO SEND)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100); //THROTTLE
            SendBytes();
        }
    }

    public void InitReceive()
    {
        socket.BeginReceive(receive_buffer, 0, receive_buffer.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), this);
    }

    public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Player player = (Player)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket socket = player.socket;

        int bytesRead = socket.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead != 0)
        {
            // READ BYTES...

            // PROCESS DATA...

            if (NEED TO SEND RESPONSE)
            {
                SendBytes();
            }

            socket.BeginReceive(player.receive_buffer, 0, player.receive_buffer.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), player);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is definitely better to use tasks and `async/await` where you can. There is a lower overhead for switching between tasks compared to switching between threads, and they typically use less memory. I've done a lot of work with an asynchronous socket server in my current job, and I noticed a huge increase in performance when switching from thread-based to task-based

Comment: To add to that, if you have the time, it's well worth looking into the classes in [`System.IO.Pipelines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines). It's fairly new, so it's a bit hard to find examples using these classes, but they are very useful for dealing with sockets and custom protocols

Comment: That code example from the link is **already** using asynchronous I/O (albeit in a legacy way) via I/O Completion ports (IOCP) and thus uses no thread.  Re-writing it to use the contemporary `async/await` might not have any net effect.  [Windows has had IOCP way before .NET came along](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports) and so just because C# code isn't using `async/await` does not necessarily mean it isn't using efficient IOCP

Comment: @MickyD The OP specifically mentioned `Thread.Sleep()` and launching a new thread for each player. Yes, using `IAsyncResult` is asynchronous and this is better than using threads, but I would still recommend using tasks over the `IAsyncResult` interface. It's a nicer interface to work with and it gives the same performance benefits. Using the `System.IO.Pipelines` classes should also see a performance boost, as they use `ValueTask` extensively and avoid unnecessary buffer allocations

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Great info! I attached some pseudo-code to my original question, wondering if it is okay to mix Thread.Sleep() and IAsyncResult without performance penalties?

Comment: @HarrisonWalters have a look at [Task vs Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4130347/2363967). `IAsyncResult` is basically the original implementation of `Task`, before `Task` and the `async/await` keywords were added to C# (You can convert it pretty easily using `Task.Factory.FromAsync(...)`). Your example doesn't actually create a thread per player. When a task completes, and you want to use the result, that callback is being run on a thread in the thread pool. This is good, it's pretty much the same as what would happen if you used `async/await`

Comment: However, when you call `Thread.Sleep()`, you are reducing the number of available threads in the pool. If you have too many connections calling `Sleep` at the same time, then all the threads in the pool will be put to sleep. I'm pretty sure C# will make sure there is always at least one active thread, so when it gets to this point it will spawn a new one. So your code is not directly creating a thread per connection, but the `Thread.Sleep()` statements will eventually cause new threads to be created. I would recommend using `Task.Delay` instead

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson You are a life saver! Thank you for the insightful comment, it answers all my questions and gives me a good idea how to proceed. The whole reason I asked the question in the first place is because I published the server a few days ago with Thread.Sleep() and the server ended up crashing almost immediately. I wonder if it was causing the limited number of threads on my Azure server to be quickly consumed.

Comment: _"The OP specifically mentioned Thread.Sleep() and launching a new thread for each player"_ - that is not what he asked at all.   Rewriting it to use `async/await` is not going to solve OPs immediate problem of throttling

Comment: Never use `Thread.Sleep` in code responsible for I/O for you run the risk of data loss.  If you want to do throttling for a particular connection then simply measure the amount of I/O performed and cease transmission after a certain limit is reached