# C# How to access label element (defined in designer) from a different class using background worker

Tags: c#, class, backgroundworker, designer

I don't know how to acces a label element (`myLabel`) from a different class outside my Control Class while using background worker.

I really don't know the correct syntax.

Thanks a lot.

This is my code:

```
    public partial class BasicControl : UserControl
    {
        // ...
        private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { myLabel.Text = "THIS WORKS!"; }));
            var moc = new MyOtherClass();
            string result = moc.myMethod();

        }
    }

    internal class MyOtherClass
    {

       public void myMethod()
       {
           myLabel.Text = "THIS DOES NOT WORK!"; // NOT WORKING
       }
    }
```

Comment: If you had actually researched the `BackgroundWorker` properly then you'd know that you MUST NOT access controls in the `DoWork` event handler. If you want to access a control during the background work then you call `ReportProgress` and access the control in the `ProgressChanged` event handler. If you want to access a control after the background work is done then you do so in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler. Those event handlers are both executed on the UI thread, unlike `DoWork`. You should not be calling `Invoke` as avoiding that is the whole point of the `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: You may benefit from [this thread](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?542316) of mine.

Comment: I definitely need to acces the control during the background work. But I do not want to show a progress bar but show current values in label element instead.

Comment: John Thank you. But I still do not know to access ProgressChanged event handler from another class.

Comment: Regardless of the `BackgroundWorker`, you should not be accessing a control in any class other than the form that that `Label` is part of. If you need to put text on that `Label` that is generated from another class then you should have a function in that class that returns that text. The form can then call that method to get the text and display it in its own `Label`. In that case, it would be the form - more specifically the user control in your case - handling the `ProgressChanged` event of the `BackgroundWorker` and your issue goes away.

Comment: The other class shouldn't need to know anything about the `BackgroundWorker` or the `Label`. If its job is to generate the text then that's ALL it should do. Think Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: *"I do not want to show a progress bar"*. Then don't. No one said you have to. Do your research first, then you would know that, while `ProgressChanged` is often used to update a progress bar, there's no reason that it has to be and you can do anything else you want regardless, given that you can pass an arbitrary object from the `ReportPorgress` method to the `ProgressChanged` event handler. The link I provided demonstrates that.

Comment: The thing is that the "other class" is called from the `BackgroundWorker`. And I really do not know how to call `bw_ProgressChanged` method from the other class.

Comment: Nothing is called "from the `BackgroundWorker`". The other class is referenced in the `DoWork` event handler of the `BackgroundWorker`, which is part of your user control. That user control is handling the `DoWork` event of the `BackgroundWorker` so it can handle the `ProgressChanged` even as well. It can then reference that other class in that event handler instead of the other.

Comment: I can understand the theory but as I stated before I do not know the syntax in which I could handle `ProgressChanged` event.

Comment: If you have a reference to the label in the other class then you already know how to do it.  Just change `this` to the name of the label: `myLabel.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { myLabel.Text = "THIS WORKS!"; }));`

Comment: ..and that's a big "IF" there. Did you actually pass a reference to the label into the other class? It's not clear what part isn't working.

Comment: @Idle_Mind It does not work. It says: "The name 'myLabel' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: It would make more sense to write ot like this:  `BasicControl.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { myLabel.Text = "THIS WORKS!"; }));` Now it is only wrong the `myLabel.Text` part with the same error as previous. The point is that I am accessing it from a different class (`MyOtherClass`).

Comment: Then when you create your class instance, you can pass a reference to the label in via the CONSTRUCTOR.  Look up an example, there are tons!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DoWorkEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs?view=net-6.0) class that you pass in your code is intended to allow interactions between the caller and the worker thread using its [Argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs.argument?view=net-6.0#system-componentmodel-doworkeventargs-argument) property. In the following example it will be set to an instance of `CustomDoWorkContext` that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Pass it when you start the worker `bw_DoWork(sender, args: new DoWorkEventArgs(argument: context))` and have the worker pass `args` on to the method `string result = moc.myMethod(args)`. This way, the outer, calling class receives `PropertyChanged` notifications *while* the thread is running *whenever* a bound property changes.

```
internal class MyOtherClass
{
    internal string myMethod(DoWorkEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Argument is CustomDoWorkContext context)
        {
            context.Message = $"THIS WORKS! @ {DateTime.Now} ";
        }
        return "Your result";
    }
}
```

---

Here is the custom class that creates context for the worker thread.

```
class CustomDoWorkContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CustomDoWorkContext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Token = cancellationToken;
    }
    // This class can have as many bindable properties as you need
    string _message = string.Empty;
    public string Message
    {
        get => _message;
        set => SetProperty(ref _message, value);
    }
    int _count = 0;
    public int Count
    {
        get => _count;
        set => SetProperty(ref _count, value);
    }
    public CancellationToken Token { get; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected bool SetProperty<T>( ref T backingStore, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))  return false;
        backingStore = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

***The key point is to subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event before starting the background worker.***

```
// Get notified when any property changes in CustomDoWorkContext.
var context = new CustomDoWorkContext(cancellationToken: _cts.Token);
context.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case nameof(CustomDoWorkContext.Message):
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            // When myMethod sets Message, change the label text.
            {  myLabel.Text = $"{context.Message}"; });
            break;
        case nameof(CustomDoWorkContext.Count):
            // When the count increments, change the checkbox text.
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            { checkBoxDoWork.Text = $"Count = {context.Count}"; });
            break;
    }
};
```

Then start the worker by passing the args (something like this).

```
// Set the `Argument` property when you start the worker.
// (Like this or something similar.)
Task.Run(() => bw_DoWork(sender, args: new DoWorkEventArgs(argument: context)));
```

---

Have the worker thread pass the args along to the `myMethod`:

```
private async void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
    var moc = new MyOtherClass();
    if (args.Argument is CustomDoWorkContext context)
    {
        args.Cancel = context.Token.IsCancellationRequested;
        while (!args.Cancel) // Loop for testing
        {
            context.Count++;
            string result = moc.myMethod(args); // Pass the args
            try { await Task.Delay(1000, context.Token); }
            catch (TaskCanceledException) { return; }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**TEST**
`BasicControl:UserControl` with checkbox and label is placed on the `MainForm`.

[image: initial state]

Toggling the checkbox starts and stops the worker after instantiating `CustomDoWorkContext`.

[image: continuous events]

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/label-element-from-background-worker.git) this example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In your solution `myMethod()` in `MyOtherClass` returns the value back to backgroundworker after it has finished. But the whole point is that `MyOtherClass` is doing the process thing and is supposed to send results continuously before it finishes.

Comment: I am talking about `MyOtherClass`. Once I use `return DateTime.Now;` the process of `myMethod()` finishes and that is exactly what I do not want.

Comment: No problem, if the `result` of `myMethod` _isn't_ what goes in myLabel.Text then all you have to do is pass the args to the `myMethod`. I made an edit to show that. The point of the answer is that the purpose of sending `DoWorkEvent` args in the first place is to be able to communicate between the caller and the thread.

Comment: This background worker thing seems rather diffucult. Anyway I am trying to implement it but I got stuck on this line: `var context = new CustomDoWorkContext(cancellationToken: _cts.Token);` It was throwing error saying: CS1739: The best overload for 'CustomDoWorkContext' does not have a parameter named 'cancellationToken'. So I changed the name to `token` but still there is an error with `_cts`. It says CS0103: The name '_cts' does not exist in the current context. This syntax is all Greek to me so I really have no idea about what to do with that.

Comment: You are quite correct. My final version of the `CustomDoWorkContext` did not make it into my edited post. I do apologize. I have fixed the typo! I do have [100% functional code on GitHub](https://github.com/IVSoftware/label-element-from-background-worker.git) to either _browse_ or _clone_. Let me know if you need any assistance with either, I'm happy to help.

Comment: Syntax-wise, you're not alone! For me, even after all these years, there's always something new  and yeah, it looks like "Greek" at first. Here's what I'd like to suggest: 1) Get it running in your Visual Studio 2) Make sure it actually _does_ answer your question. 3) Learn the unfamiliar syntax by setting breakpoints to see _why_ it works. 4) Ask more questions if they come up 5) Use your new understanding to modify it and adapt it to you own uses. Not just _this_ example but _any_ :)

Comment: Ok, I finally made it work! There were a few issues with arguments that I had to work out. I also found out that your solution is not based on the actual `backgroundworker` but rather a separate `thread` running asynchronously. It took me a while to notice that. I also need to process the result of the bw that I had in my `bw_RunWorkerCompleted` method so I changed it to `var result = await Task.Run(() => bw_DoWork(sender, args: new DoWorkEventArgs(argument: context)));` and made proper adjustments. Anyway it works now. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help in a big way.

Comment: Nice job! And I'm glad you said that because (unless I missed it) I didn't really see `BackgroundWorker` _in your actual code_ that you posted. I'm guessing that might be part of the reason it got a downvote (consider editing your post)? Without that, I accomplished the same thing using `Task`. Here's a great SO post that might add to your understanding: [What is the difference between task and thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4130194/5438626)