# Threads, Tasks, async and await, how do they actually work?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task, threadpool

I’m currently learning about C#, I’m wondering how `Thread`, `Task`, `async` and `await` really work. This is what I understand:

- `Task.Run(MyTask)` is always executed on a new thread (in the thread pool)
- Because of this, `Task` will run in parallel with the method that calls it (because they are on two different threads)
- Therefore, use await to wait for the result of that `Task`, then continue executing the code below.
- This is my example code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(MyTask);
    Console.WriteLine("Do main work...");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}

static async Task MyTask()
{
    await MyMiniTask();
    Console.WriteLine("Do Task...");
}

static async Task MiniTask()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Do Mini Task...");
}
```

output:
Do main work...
Do Mini Task...
Do Task...
As I understand it, the code should run like this:

- Run program -> Main thread is initialized to run the program
- `Task.Run(MyTask)` -> thread A in the thread pool will handle `MyTask`
- In the output, print out “Do main work…” first, even though the console writeline is written after `Task.Run(MyTask)`. The reason is because Main thread and thread A are two different threads, so they will be executed in parallel
- Back to thread A and `MyTask`, it encounters the statement: await MiniTask -> thread B in the thread pool will handle `MiniTask` (a new thread will always be used to handle `MiniTask` even if there is no `await`)
- Because of using `await`, `MyTask` will have to wait for `MiniTask` to complete, and while waiting, thead A of MyTask does not handle anything -> MyTask will be marked as "a pause point" here and C# will release thread A back to the thread pool, thread A can now do another job
- When `MiniTask` is completed, C# will return to "the pause point" of `MyTask`, and handle it with another thread in the `ThreadPool` (it could be thread A or any other free thread)

=> The meaning of using async await is: it will wait for the result of the asynchronous task (`MiniTask`), await keyword when used will release the thread of the method that calls it (Thread A of `MyTask`), and `ThreadPool` will allocate another thread to continue processing this method after MiniTask has completed.

There is a difference between using the `Wait()` method of `Task` and the keyword `await`, which is `Wait()` will not release the thread of the method that calls it (I have tried)

=>> Summary (according to my understanding):

- When you want to perform multiple tasks in parallel without affecting the main thread -> use `Thread`, and now more modern is `Task`
- When you want to wait for the result of a `Task` -> `Wait()` it
- When you want to wait for the result of a `Task`, but want to release the Thread of the method that calls that `Task` in the waiting time -> `await` it

**I don't know if I understand that right?**

 **Sorry if my English is not good**

This example code actually works and prints the output as above.
But I don't know if it works the way I think or just a coincidence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between task and thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130194/what-is-the-difference-between-task-and-thread)

Comment: Bookmark this blog : https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html

Comment: Just because you mentioned `Task.Wait` I have to add that you must use is with caution (it's usually avoidable). When a `Task` is created it captures the current `SynchronizationContext` of the caller and the continuation code (code after `await` or defined by the `Task.ContinueWith` delegate). This is required to enable the `Task` to execute the continuations. By default a `Task` is configured to execute the continuation on the caller's `SynchronizationContext` i.e. the caller's thread. This means `Task.ConfigureAwait` is implicitly configured with `Task.ConfigureAwait(true)`.

Comment: Unless you explicitly allow the `Task` to execute the continuation on the current thread by calling `Task.ConfigureAwait(false)` calling `Task.Wait` to wait for the `Task` object to run to completion will cause a deadlock. This is because, as you correctly mentioned, that `Task.Wait` will block the caller's thread until the `Task` has returned. This is effectively a common synchronous method invocation behavior.

Comment: Because of the default `Task.ConfigureAwait(true)` configuration the `Task` is forced to return to the caller's thread in order to continue to execute the continuation using the captured `SynchronizationContext`. But the caller's thread is busy with waiting for the `Task` to complete. So the `Task` has to wait until the calling thread is available to allow the `Task` to return, which can never happen because the caller's thread is blocked with waiting for the `Task`. That's the deadlock.

Comment: If you configure the `Task` to continue on a thread pool thread by calling `Task.ConfigureAwait(false)` the deadlock is lifted because the `Task` no longer has to return to the caller's thread and therefore `Task.Wait` won't stop the `Task` from completion. It's an important detail to understand. `Task.Wait`, Task.WaitAny` and `Task.WaitAll` have the same behavior in this regards. That's why you must always avoid the `Waitx` API and instead replace `Taks.Wait` ==> `await Task`,  `Task.WaitAny`==> àwait Task.WhenAny` and `Task.WaitAll` ==> `await Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: It's also best practice for library code that is not expected to run in an UI environment to always configure *every* `Task` using `Task.ConfigureAwait(false)` to prevent this deadlock from happening in the client code (and of course to improve the performance by eliminating the `SynchronizationContext` context switch).

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is mostly OK. One point that needs to be corrected is here:

> `Task.Run(MyTask)` is always executed on a new thread (in the thread pool)

Not on **a new** thread. The whole point of having a [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) is to reuse a small number of threads, in order to avoid paying the cost of creating a new thread each time a thread is needed to do some minuscule work. So it's just **a** thread, not **a new** thread.